# Overriding Spring MVC context config location generates error

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, tcserver

I keep getting this error when trying to initialize my app (it seems to actually work fine but its disconcerting)

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class 

org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-mango/root-context.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-mango/root-context.xml]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:397)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1585)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-mango/root-context.xml]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:117)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328)
    ... 26 more
```

I have set the location of the config file in `context.xml` of the webserver as seen here (this is in SpringSource ToolSuite 2.9.2 with tc server 2.7)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
    <!--
            <Manager pathname="" />
            -->
    <!-- Uncomment this to enable Comet connection tacking (provides events
                 on session expiration as well as webapp lifecycle) -->
    <!--
            <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.CometConnectionManagerValve" />
            -->
    <Loader loaderClass="com.springsource.insight.collection.tcserver.ltw.TomcatWeavingInsightClassLoader"/>
    <Listener className="com.springsource.insight.collection.tcserver.lifecycle.ApplicationLifecycleCollectionListener"/>

    <Parameter name="contextConfigLocation" value="/WEB-INF/spring-mango/root-context.xml" override="false"/>

</Context>
```

The web.xml file can be found here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
      <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>encoding</param-name>
      <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>HttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>HttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and the root-context file found here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <interceptors>
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.ThemeChangeInterceptor"/>
    </interceptors>

    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.ui.context.support.ResourceBundleThemeSource" id="themeSource"/>
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.CookieThemeResolver" id="themeResolver" 
                p:cookieName="theme" p:defaultThemeName="default"/>

    <!-- Support for multipart form data as parameters to controllers -->
    <!-- NOTE: the maxUploadSize limit, we must be aware of DB sizes and increase this if necessary -->
    <beans:bean id="multipartResolver" p:maxInMemorySize="5000000"
            class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"
            p:maxUploadSize="150000000"/>

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jspx resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <!-- 
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jspx" />
    </beans:bean>
     -->

    <!-- Tiles Configuration -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver" id="tilesViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView"/>
    </beans:bean>




    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer" id="tilesConfigurer">
        <beans:property name="definitions"> 
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>/WEB-INF/layouts/layouts.xml</beans:value> 
                <!-- Scan views directory for Tiles configurations --> 
                <beans:value>/WEB-INF/views/**/views.xml</beans:value>
            </beans:list> 
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.kwhours.mango.web.controller" />

    <beans:import resource="classpath:mango-app-context.xml"/>

    <beans:import resource="classpath:mango-app-security.xml"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.kwhours.mango.service.jpa"/>



</beans:beans>
```

so what I am trying to figure out is why the contextLoaderListener is not able to find this file which is at the directory specified. Do I need to somehow make it available to the contextLoaderListener somewhere else?

Comment: Since the root cause is a `FileNotFound`, I'm betting that the file isn't actually where you think it is. Howe are you building your WAR? And have you actually looked at the files in the deployed WAR?

Comment: I made a war and looked at the files and the files it is exactly at this location.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the exception stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-mango/root-context.xml
```

Your application is looking for the file /WEB-INF/spring-mango/root-context.xml, yet you have the following referred to in your web.xml:

- /WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml
- /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml

But you have the following in your context.xml:

```
<Parameter name="contextConfigLocation" value="/WEB-INF/spring-mango/root-context.xml" override="false"/>
```

So what is your application meant to look for? Perhaps you need to remove the entry in your context.xml.